# Logo image in the navbar displays only on home page

Tags: python, django

The image of my logo on the navbar displays only on the home page, what should I do to fix it?
That's root for the image on the navbar:

```
    <a class="navbar-brand waves-effect" href="/">
     <img src="media\logoBrand.png">
   </a>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
  path('', include('core.urls', namespace='core'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
   import debug_toolbar
   urlpatterns += [path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))]
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And urls.py core:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import (
   ItemDetailView,
   CheckoutView,
   HomeView,
   OrderSummaryView,
   add_to_cart,
   remove_from_cart,
   remove_single_item_from_cart,
   PaymentView,
   AddCouponView,
   RequestRefundView
   )

  app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('order-summary/', OrderSummaryView.as_view(), name='order-summary'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
    path('add-to-cart/<slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
    path('add-coupon/', AddCouponView.as_view(), name='add-coupon'),
    path('remove-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
    path('remove-item-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_single_item_from_cart,
     name='remove-single-item-from-cart'),
    path('payment/<payment_option>/', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment'),
    path('request-refund/', RequestRefundView.as_view(), name='request-refund')

     ]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So when i got to homepage the image is displaying, but when I go to let say /checkout/ i get an error in the console: 
Not Found: /checkout/media/logoBrand.png

I am not sure why does it go to this directory

Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a relative path, that's why your browser is trying to download `/checkout/media/logoBrand.png`. You should change it to an absolute one, i.e. change:

```
<img src="media\logoBrand.png">
```

to

```
<img src="/media/logoBrand.png">
```

Note the use of forward slashes, that are cross platform.

As a side note, you shouldn't keep static assets (such as your logo) in the media folder as media is generally used for visitor uploaded resources. Use the `static` folder for such things and use the `{% static %}` template tag and Django will take care of paths:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'logoBrand.png' %}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help and advice, everything is sorted now!